# How can i print every second letter first and then starting word in Python 3. eg my string = "stackoverflow" iwant result as "tscavorelfwo"

Tags: python-3.x, string

I want to print every next letter before first letter.

```
string = "stackoveerflow"

for i in len((string)-1):
    print(i)
    a = string[i+1] + string[i]
    print(a)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple approach would be the following (recursive) function:

```
def reverse_chunks(s, n=2):
    if not s:
        return s
    return s[:n][::-1] + reverse_chunks(s[n:])

>>> reverse_chunks("stackoverflow")
'tscaokevfrolw'
```

Of course, there are more performant iterative approaches.